# are these the same series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that the series are equal
$$ \sum\limits_{l=-\infty}^{k} v(k-l) =\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} v(j)<\infty  $$
I have done this

in $ \sum\limits_{l=-\infty}^{k} v(k-l) $, let $ j=k-l $ then 
$$\sum\limits_{l=-\infty}^{k} v(k-l)=\sum\limits_{j=\infty}^{0} v(j) $$ but $$ \sum\limits_{j=\infty}^{0} v(j)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum\limits_{j=n}^{0} v(j)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n} v(j)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} v(j) $$

my proof is right??

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: What is $< \infty$ supposed to mean?

Comment: $\infty$ means that $v(j)$ is a summable function. I forgot the $\vert\;  \vert$